# How to move Mapbox watermark to right corner in Android?

Tags: android, mapbox

How to move the Mapbox watermark from the left corner to the right or top right corner in Android using the latest version 5.0.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approved answer doesn't work anymore as of Mapbox 10.0.

In the newest mapbox you can adjust logo and attributions position like this, from code:

```kotlin
mapView.logo.updateSettings {
    position = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.RIGHT
}

mapView.attribution.updateSettings {
    position = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.RIGHT
}
```

From XML:

```xml
app:mapbox_logoGravity="right|bottom"
app:mapbox_attributionGravity="right|bottom"
```

Answer (score 1):

`app:mapbox_uiLogoGravity="right|end|bottom"` and [other attributes](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/src/main/res-public/values/public.xml) can be used in combination inside your Mapview in the layout XML to move around the Mapbox logo and attribution button.

If you want to handle this dynamically, you can either set it in MapboxMapOptions before the views created or `mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setAttributionGravity();` for example when the map is already being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to move:

```
mapView?.apply {
   logo.updateSettings { marginBottom = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65f, resources.displayMetrics) }
   attribution.updateSettings { marginBottom = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65f, resources.displayMetrics) }
}
```